# Mouse events on overlay image interfering

Tags: events, mouse, overlay

I've added a few overlay images which I'm using as buttons/control for showing / hiding some custom layers and this works fine, however they still trigger the usual drag/move events on the map.  This isn't that bad but when you go into street view and you click on on of these (the buttons are on the left of the screen) the camera shifts it's view to the left which is going to be very annoying for the users.

Just wondered if someone has encountered this and have advice?  I guess I can move the buttons out of the maps area completely but it looks really nice on the map with the standard controls.

Thanks a lot!